# How to get url from url in React and pass to a state

Tags: reactjs

So I want to do an invite link in React from example: `/invite/e04d2h`, and then a component it will load, so that will have an input to enter the playing code, and what I want to do is get that data in this case: `e04d2he` from url and put to the input (state) automatically so he just can click enter to enter/play it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet will give you the code:

```
const playingCode = /[^/]*$/.exec(window.location.href)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have URL like `/invite/e04d2h` as you mentioned in your question, you might try this as well.

```js
const getCode = (url) => {
    const link = url;
    let splitedLink = link.split('/');
    return splitedLink[splitedLink.length-1]; // e04d2h
}

getCode("/invite/e04d2h");
```

This will split the URL by `/` and get the last one.